# Javascript replace multiple characters in string not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Replace `<b>` and `</b>` with space " " and `<br>` with \n

```
var a  = "Welcome to xyz. You have been added as a manager by <b>Adam </b>.<br><br><b>Dashboard Link:</b> https://app.xyz.com <br><br>Use the credentials below to sign-in: <br><b>Username : </b>a@k.com<br><b>Password : </b>qwerty";

var b = a.replace("<b>|</b>"," ").replace("<br>","\n");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: `"<b>|</b>"` replaces _literal strings_ `"<b>|</b>"`. You need a _regex_ here.

Comment: could you please provide a code for that @Xufox

Comment: `/<b>|<\/b>/g`.

Comment: var a  = "Welcome to xyz. You have been added as a manager by <b>Adam </b>.<br><br><b>Dashboard Link:</b> https://app.xyz.com <br><br>Use the credentials below to sign-in: <br><b>Username : </b>a@k.com<br><b>Password : </b>qwerty";

var b = a.replace(/<b>|<\/b>/g," ").replace(/<br>/g,"\n");
console.log(b);

worked

Answer (score 0):

@repeated [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273791/replace-all-substrings-in-javascript-with-infuenced-string) you can use regular expression or slit and joint function to achieve it.for multiple character use regex